# How to return more than one thing in if statement?

Tags: javascript

I want to display all the product which fulfilled a condition.

```
    if(correctSize === 3 || correctSize === 4) {return  key == "3kw" }
    if(correctSize === 4 || correctSize === 5) {return  key == "4kw"} 
    if(correctSize === 5 || correctSize === 6) {return  key == "5kw" } 
    if(correctSize === 6 || correctSize === 7) {return  key == "6kw" }
```

but the problem is that it return just one object (the first with return).

2. there is easy way to say the statement is true if correctSize is from 4 to 6?

Comment: How about `correctSize >= 4 && correctSize <= 6`?

Comment: Return an array

Comment: why don't you maintain an object whose keys are sizes and whose values are array of ??? As per your text, you are returning a boolean, is that intended?

Comment: Also.. please clarify... For a given size of `4`, do you want to return `"3kw"` and `"4kw"` both or just a single value which is `true` or `false` depending upon the value of `key`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an array of results and push your answers inside.
For example:

```js
let results= [];
if(correctSize === 3 || correctSize === 4) results.push("3kw");
if(correctSize === 4 || correctSize === 5) results.push("4kw"); 
if(correctSize === 5 || correctSize === 6) results.push("5kw"); 
if(correctSize === 6 || correctSize === 7) results.push("6kw");
return results;
```

Comment: This display me all item in array I got ``` return arrayOfHope.map((props)=> {return key == props})
 ```